# Unix: Delayed stderr display

Tags: unix, reporting, stderr

Is there a way to display errors summary (from `stderr`) after an application has finished?

E.g. `rsync` with "--progress" displays LOTS of data, including errors. But when it finishes - it just says "there were errors". I want to display everything that was written to stderr in that case, so i don't have to scroll and search what precisely went wrong :)

P.S. I know how simple it is to write such utility in C, but i guess there can be more handy things i'm not aware of :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wrapper script to handle this:

```
#!/bin/sh

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

"$@" 2>$TMPFILE

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
  cat $TMPFILE
fi
```

If you save this to `/usr/local/bin/delaystderr` and `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/delaystderr`, you should be able to run as `delaystderr rsync --progress`.  If the process exits without signalling error (returning non-zero), stderr won't be printed; you can delete the lines starting with `if` and `fi` to disable that behaviour if you like.

I'm not sure how you'd get any easier than that.

(Note: I haven't actually tested this script, so buyer beware and all that)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to womble's answer, you can write a bash script something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

exec 2>$TMPFILE
trap 'cat "$TMPFILE"; rm -f "$TMPFILE" exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

command1
command2
command3
```

and this should save everything sent to stderr for the entire script and output it at the end. As with womble's answer, I've not tested this.

Comment: I don't know how many errors Gary is getting but if it's a lot then "easier" might mean that `cat` should be replaced by `more` or `less`.

Comment: less in a script is annoying. If you want to page the output, pipe the script into less. It's more flexible that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash redirect stderr to stdout then, optionally, redirect that to a file:

```
rsync --progress 2>&1
rsync --progress 2>&1 > file.out
```

Comment: That's true, thanks, but i'd like to find something that does the job easier :)